# Link Within an App with the React Native Render Html

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, expo, react-native-render-html

In my expo / react app I have some HTML from a website that I'm pulling from an api.  I'd like to use links within that html to link to pages within the app.  Some example html...

```
responseHtml = "<p>this is a paragraph <a href="http://example.com/some-page">Some Page</a><p>"
```

then I was thinking I would do some string replace so that the html ends up looking like this...

```
responseHtml = "<p>this is a paragraph <a href="exp://something/Article/some-page">Some Page</a><p>"
```

Then I would render the content in my app and the links would work if I did something like this...

```
<HTML onLinkPress={(event, href)=>{Linking.openURL(href)}} html="{responseHtml}" />
```

I cannot seem to find the right href value to make a successful click to a page within the app.  I've tried using the full path, `exp://127.0.0.1:19200/Article/some-page`, I've tried relative links like `/Article/some-page`, and I've tried setting a schema value to "myapp" in the app.json and linking to it with `myapp://Article/some-page`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to parse it ? I would use the [react-native-htmlview](https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview) library. There you can customize the Link handler. So you could open the link or pass it down as prop.
Your code could be look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import HTMLView from 'react-native-htmlview';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const responseHTML = ``;

    return (
      <HTMLView
        value={htmlContent}
        stylesheet={{
         fontWeight: '300',
         color: '#FF3366', // make links coloured pink
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to do any custom actions with your link it could look like this:

```
return (
  <HTMLView
    value={this.props.putyourhtmlhere}
    onLinkPress={(url) => console.log('clicked link: ', url)}
  />
);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Is it possible to get the value from onclick?.. like responseHtml = "<p>this is a paragraph <a href="#" onclick ="exp://something/Article/some-page>Some Page</a><p>"

Comment: you can do simply 
onLinkPress={ (evt, href) => { Linking.openURL(href); }}